# Real and Imaginary

Tags: complex-numbers

$$Re\Big(({\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i})^4\Big)} = 2$$

$$Im\Big(({\frac{1+i}{1-i})^5\Big)} = 1$$

I got that $Re\Big(({\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i})^4\Big)} = 1 \ne 2$

And, that $\Big(({\frac{1+i}{1-i})^5\Big)} = i $ , which means that $Im\Big(({\frac{1+i}{1-i})^5\Big)} = 1$

Can you guys confirm that it's true? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry but [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281%2Bi*sqrt%283%29%29%2F%281-i%29%29%5E4) says 2.

Comment: You mean that $Re(something) =2$? If so, can you post how you solved it?

Comment: Do you mind to explain what you have done?

Comment: [link](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/q83/s720x720/10252035_10152425249402915_4542436710338370870_n.jpg) Here's a picture, and in the end it's $ i = 1 $ I did a mistake :)

Comment: I do not understand how did you get that third step.... It is not actually readable.. what have you written just after $$\big(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}+i+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\big)^4$$?

Comment: I just get everything $^4$

Comment: $1^4 = 1,i^4 = 1,$ and so on..

Comment: What is your point? I believe you know that $(a+b)^4\neq a^4+b^4$

Comment: So how can I continue from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your link for the solution: first one is actually easier if you just use the [Binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) on both the numerator and denominator and then just simplify. The second one, the way you have done it is fine.

First notice that $(1-i)^4=1-4i+6i^2-4i^3+i^4=1-6+1-4i+4i=-4$. So if we only find the real part of the numerator we are done. Now  $Re(1+i\sqrt{3})^4=Re(1+4i\sqrt{3}+6i^2(3)+4i^3(3\sqrt{3})+i^43^2)=1-18+9=-8$, and then $\frac{-8}{-4}=2$ as required.

The second one, as mentioned, your method is good...

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
1+i\sqrt{3}=2\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=
2(\cos(\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3))
$$
so
$$
(1+i\sqrt{3})^4=16\cos(4\pi/3)+i\sin(4\pi/3)=
16\left(-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right).
$$
On the other hand
$$
1-i=\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=
\sqrt{2}(\cos(-\pi/4)+i\sin(-\pi/4))
$$
so
$$
(1-i)^4=4(\cos(-\pi)+i\sin(-\pi))=-4.
$$
Therefore
$$
\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i}\right)^4=
\frac{8(-1-i\sqrt{3})}{-4}=
2+2i\sqrt{3}.
$$
Similarly, $1+i=\sqrt{2}(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))$, so
$$
\frac{1+i}{1-i}=
\frac{\sqrt{2}(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))}{\sqrt{2}(\cos(-\pi/4)+i\sin(-\pi/4))}=
\cos(\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/2)=i
$$
and so its fifth power is again $i$. Perhaps more easy, in this case, is
$$
\frac{1+i}{1-i}=\frac{(1+i)(1+i)}{(1-i)(1+i)}=\frac{1+2i+i^2}{1+1}=i.
$$

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thank you!